# R: Going from a data.frame with weight variable to a regular data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame or matrix in the following form:

Name of Columns: `X`, `Y`, `Freq`:

```
a, 1, 3
b, 4, 2
```

The last column is a weight variable. How do I transform it into a data.frame/matrix without the weight?

```
a, 1
a, 1
a, 1
b, 4
b, 4
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this using simple subseting:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c('a','b'),y=c(1,4),wt = c(3,2))
dat[rep(1:nrow(dat),times = dat$wt),1:2]
```

which produces this:

```
    x y
1   a 1
1.1 a 1
1.2 a 1
2   b 4
2.1 b 4
```

Comment: +1 This is essentially the R way of doing a `rep.data.frame()` method without implementing it. This was discussed on R-Devel recently IIRC with no-less than Martin Maechler advocating this indexing solution (though the initial indexing solution was supplied by David Winsemius IIRC).

Comment: Thank you very much Joran. I knew there had to be a way more elegant that a for loop. It doesn't get any better than a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Several options spring to mind, using your data as an example:

```
dat <- data.frame(X = c("a", "b"), Y = c(1,4), Freq = c(3,2), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The first options is:

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(dat[,-3], rep, times = dat[,3]))
```

And the second is a little function:

```
foo <- function(dat) {
    data.frame(X = rep(dat$X, times = dat$Freq),
               Y = rep(dat$Y, times = dat$Freq))
}
foo(dat)
```

And another is:

```
> with(dat, dat[, 1:2][rep(seq_along(Freq), times = Freq),])
    X Y
1   a 1
1.1 a 1
1.2 a 1
2   b 4
2.1 b 4
```

Comment: Oops, the last one is a variant on @joran's Answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you too Gavin. I like your first solution a lot.